# Create procedure/function working for different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-function

As far as I know, there is no possibility in MySQL to pass a table handle. So the question is how to write a procedure/function that works for different tables. Is it neccessary to hardcode table names in every proc/fun? Let's say I want to `doSomethingWithTable(...)` and am I forced to create one for every table even if it's exactly the same operation? Do I really need to create X times same proc/fun changing only its name (`doSomethingWithTableClients(...)`, `doSomethingWithTableUsers(...)`, `doSomethingWithTableItems(...)` and so on)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to pass the table name as variable use dynamic SQL to perform whatever you wish to do.

It's actually quite rare that you would do same things on all tables in a procedure. Things like changing charcter sets / collations come to mind but usually in procedures there is logic involved and that logic differs from table to table.

Comment: My tables have composite keys built from 4 keys and have few same columns like ,,name", ,,status" etc. I have function e.g. getName(id1, id2, id3, id4) and it will be much simpler if I have one function for every table instead of X same functions for each table.

Comment: Consider what really is the benefit of using the stored procedure in that case. You can do the same in direct SQL query if you anyways create the query dynamically.